# XCODE auto save code when build and run?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, build, autosave

How to tell Xcode to save the source code automatically without prompting, each time I hit on the build and run?

Comment: too bad this answer doesn't work at all for Xcode 5 versions.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

1. Xcode preferences
2. Pick 'Building' tab
3. Lower right corner "For unsaved files:" pick "Always save".

Answer (score 4):

Xcode Preferences → Building → Build Options → For Unsaved Files → Always Save?

Answer (score 0):

it seems this is the default behaviour in the current xcode 5.
hopefully it will return so we can turn it `OFF` and dont have this painfully slow rebuild.