# How can I speed up compile time when using many extern type declarations

Tags: c++, xcode, compilation, extern, performance

### The Project:

C++ Programming in **xcode**. I have over 3,000+ type definitions spread over 2,000+ .c/.h files. Each `myType` type contains a string description. I used a script to define a `map<std::string, myType>` of 3,000+ elements in a `.cpp` file to use for looking up a `myType` type to pass to a function that processes data based on which `myType` is passed to it. Because the `myType` definitions are spread over 2,000+ files, I used a script to write each `extern myType TYPENAME;` in a header file.

**Overview:**

(2,000+ `.c` files with `myType`definitions)

`myTypes.h` (contains all the extern `myType` statements for each `myType` in the above files)

`myTypes.cpp` (contains the `map<std::string, myType>` of 3,000+ elements in the above files)

`typeProcessor.cpp` (includes `myTypes.h`. Uses the map defined in `myTypes.cpp` to match a string to a `myType`. Passes the `myType` to a function from the file below)

`dataProcessor.cpp` (processes data based on the `myType` passed to it)

### The Problem:

Since I've added `myTypes.h` with 3,000+ extern statements and `myTypes.cpp` with a map of 3,000+ elements my project compile time has lengthened from 20 seconds to 1-1.5 hours.

**My Question:**

Without touching the 2,000+ files or the `dataProcessor.cpp` that receives the `myType`, what can I do to reduce the compile time?

Some thoughts I've had:

1. use a script to put all the `myType` definitions into one big `myTypes.cpp` file and remove the extern statements. **or**
2. use a script to `#include` each of the 2,000+ files containing the `myType` definitions

I don't know much about compilers, the main factors on compile time, and how to write code to minimize compile time. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: It sounds like the code is very poorly structured ?

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of many things you could do/have done to structure your code better, why don't you

- create a public static registration function e.g. (typemap.h)

.

```
std::map<std::string, myTypeBase>& getGlobalTypeMap();
# define getGlobalTypeMap _once_ in typemap.cpp !

template <class myType>
  registerTypeMapping(std::string name, const myType& instance)
  {
       getGlobalTypeMap().insert(name, instance);
  }
```

- In every .cpp for a type definition, call the registration function. That way a type registers itself, and there is no need for the type map to 'know all the types'. This is inversion of dependency, in a simple form
- The crux is, that no file needs to include all the type headers for the registration process. You'll still need to include (selected) type headers if you need interfaces specific to the subtype (e.g. when using `dynamic_cast<subtype>` on a map element)

PS. I'm assuming some kind of common base type for myType (because there is no way you could get the `std::map<std::string, myType>` to compile otherwise)

#### Update

**Edit**

- Yes, you can make `registerTypeMapping` an `extern "C"` function (just edit the prototype to be C-conforming)
- For each `type_xx.h/type_xx.c` combi you can always *generate* an extra source file `type_xx_register.c` that includes *just* that type and registers it.

Note that this will lead to *more* sources but will likely reduce compile times. Especially, if you have a makefile and only compile the `type_xx_register.o` object file when it's dependencies truly changed.

That way, only a change in `typemap.h` would cause a recompilation of all these files.

<sub>*It is also not impossible that a simple*</sub>

```
$CC type*_register.cpp -o
```

_would be faster than the compilation of a single source including all type_xx.h at once_

Comment: but then program startup will be slow

Comment: why would it be any slower than your version? The same types get registered in the same map. Profile it.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you mean to call that registration function in every .c (2,000+ of them) file that defines a type? If that's the case, there's two problems. The first is that the myTypes are defined in C, not C++ files. Perhaps I can impliment the register function in C but more importantly is the 2nd problem that I am not allowed to modify the existing C code that contains the myType definitions. As for the base type, myType is the base type. An example would be one of the C files having some functions and the myType definition: "myType A = { "A", 0, foo, bar, 0}; and so on.

Comment: Wait... all the extern instances are _not_ types? They're _just_ variable declarations? Then I'd think that including all is the fastest possible way. Have you considered creating a precompiled header for those [gcc](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Precompiled-Headers.html) [msvc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/szfdksca(v=vs.71).aspx) [borland](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE/en/Precompiled_Headers_Overview)?

Answer (score 0):

As all these files don't change much (I'm assuming), it's either parsing the 3000+ line header or linking that kills the compile time. If it's parsing, a precompiled header should solve that, if it's linking, something like Visual Studio's incremental linking should help out, but I don't think any compiler except MSVC has this capability (correct me if I'm wrong).

Answer (score 0):

it might be a matter of preventing a save on those 3,000 files

do the opposite of [the xcode autosave method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2271031/xcode-auto-save-code-when-build-and-run)

this `autosave off` option is (very foolish) missing in newer versions of xcode (3.1 is a solid xcode) thus all files get a new timestamp and then the equivalent of a clean all rebuild.

try `make` on the commandline that doesn't save files as a speed comparison.