# XCode 4.2 on OSX 10.7.1 (Lion) Crashing/Locking Up all the time. Anyone Know how to fix?

Tags: ios, xcode4, xcode4.2

This should not create any Issues with the NDA as I am not asking anyone to reveal any functionality of the application, I have asked on the Developer Forums, but They dont have the user base or the response speed of StackOverflow.

I have been working with XCode for a while now. And other then these issues, I REALLY LIKE the new xcode. I will (when these issues are resolved) recommend this application to all iOS/OSX developers.

Anyhow.

I am currently developing iOS applications. And am Running this setup on Mac OSX 10.7.1 (Lion)

Issue 1:

If I use the Interface builder it will first of all stay open even after I navigate away from it and it is no longer visible or to my knowledge "running". After a while it will consume more then 4 gigs of active memory. I will have the activity monitor open and Will eventually have less than 20megs left of free memory. I upgraded my MacMini to 8 Gigs of memory and at this point it will get down to about 200 Megs of memory left and will eventually release the memory that IB had held onto. If I do not open IB in XCode 4 it tends to use a lot less memory. (adding 8 gigs of memory makes this memory leak a lot less of a problem)

Issue 2: (MOST ANNOYING, HOPING FOR A FIX TO THIS ONE MOST)

This one only currently happens on one of the Three machines I code on. And what happens is while programming if I [Run] the app it will work for a while. Then at some point through the process it will begin to Lock Up when I press Run or Command-R. If I save the code file and run. It will not lock up. However if I forget to save, It will not only lock up. But will force me to terminate the XCode app, and Subsequently Recode everything that I had edited since the last save and the Application Run. This is by far the most annoying bug I have encountered this far.

Issue 3:

This bug happens more and more often the longer the application and operating system has been running. Running into the iPad will give me a number of Errors including "Unable to Connect to Debugger" or "Finished Successfully" among others. But the important part of this issue is that the application will never get sent to the iOS device. It will compile and say it finished. But there will be a error in the output pane.

I hope others have encountered these errors and Hopefully there is a quick fix with config files or something that will make development a lot more convenient. Thanks to anyone for resolution to any of these issues.....

**EDIT**

I finally received an email from apple support. I have emailed them off a Capture from XCode 4 and will hopefully hear something from them. Or maybe they will just release a new beta. Either way I hope to get this resolved asap.

Comment: Xcode 4.2 is currently in beta, and the entire tool is under NDA.  Instability is to be expected, so instead of reporting it here, I recommend filing bugs at https://bugreport.apple.com .

Comment: Yes I know. But it seems that there is very little response on there. I was hoping others had run into these issues and maybe found a way around the most annoying of them.

Comment: Don't expect a response when filing a bug report, but to make sure the engineers know to fix it, you need to file on it.  If it gets marked as a duplicate, great, it'll move up the list of priorities.  Also, just because this place has more active users than the Apple Developer Forums does not make it the most appropriate place to ask a question about beta-stage products.  I'd still ask there for workarounds instead of here.

Comment: I did ask there. and the problem is the question has not even been looked at. Much less answered. So I got annoyed and asked here. With generic information so as not to reveal anything about the app

Comment: Now that we know this was an issue with beta software not working correctly, this can be relegated to the dustbin of "not a programming question".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the new Beta GM Release they have seemingly fixed the issue with the Hanging.

Thanks for the Answers. Ill +1 anyone who helped but ultimately it was apple that fixed the issue.... For now

Answer (score 1):

For issue #2 you might want to try auto-saving your code before runs. See [XCODE auto save code when build and run?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2271031/xcode-auto-save-code-when-build-and-runnfor) instructions. Not sure if these instructions will work for 4.2 but you get the idea.

Comment: Well this is the default functionality in XCode 4. And I dont see a setting is the Preferences any longer. But I think the issue is that the app locks up during the file save and never actually saves the file. and since it does not get past the save it never compiles. Furthermore it locks up so I cant do anything other than terminate the application and start over. Thank you for the information tho. It was a good idea

Comment: Dang. If its hanging before writing the files out then that won't help. Just to give you one more bit of info - I've been using xcode 4.2 since beta 1 and have not had these issues. Although, i do have to restart it once a day.

Comment: I have it running on three machines. Issue 2 only occurs on my main computer at home..... Oh. Maybe it has something to do with OSX Lion. I should add that to the question.

Answer (score 1):

I had issues with my Xcode 4.2 install crashing initially. Re-running the installer over the already installed Xcode 4.2 fixed them. Obviously I don't know what the underlying issue with the install was, but although the first install reported installation was successful, obviously it wasn't. Perhaps worth trying.

When a newer version of Xcode 4.2 becomes available to you (cough), you might want to see whether installing that one fixes the problem. Perhaps given the issues, you should try uninstalling the previous version first rather than installing over the top?

Comment: good idea. I will download the installer right now. Let you know how it goes.

Comment: Unfortunately I was unable to correct the problem with this. I reinstalled and was able to lock up the XCode in less than a minute.

Answer (score 1):

Do you use multiple windows? They are anathema to Xcode 4. If you persist in your heresy, it may corrupt some files, and slow itself down. You will see a lot of beachballing, and it will be in some sort of GC.

You can work around this by deleting a workspace-specific file hidden inside your project. (I will have to look up which one, if this describes your case.)

Comment: your comment seems more comical then constructive. Are your sure you are using the right words for the information you are trying to convey ? It seems like you are trying to put a curse on me if I use multiple windows..... The problem is not project specific anyhow so I dont think the multiple windows thing is an issue.

Comment: It's true though. I am again away from quick access to the details, but a file inside the project got severely bloated, and deleting it made Xcode relatively snappy again. (It was one that saved workspace configuration, which is obviously trivial if you go with the one-window approach.)

Comment: well if you can provide me with that file. I will give it a try. Even tho this was occurring before I knew about multiple windows. the bloat usually happens after I open the IB and then go on to something else. Weather I leave IB open or not the Memory slowly gets chewed up. And as for the lockup there is no beachball. Just wont let me move the caret or interact with the window. Even pressing it from the dock wont activate it. Just total lockout.

Comment: Abnormally big files in the xcuserdata folder (inside the .xcodeproj).